# Aliens Attack Apartments?

Tags: visual, real

<sup>Difficulty level**:** fair to middling        

Pose level**:** too tempting to resist</sup>  
When attempting to fill in a bureaucratic blank,
a friend serendipitously snapped this
cameraphone picture . . .

[image]

. . . of what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To me it looks like picture shows

> a car window, with the street buildings reflected in the glass, and a ventilation grill in the dashboard on the other side of the glass.

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar idea as well. +1

Comment: That was my immediate thought upon seeing the image! Of course, rot16(wi zkbdxob kxn s vyfo nysxq dbsmu zrydyqbkzri gsdr zvkic yx vsqrd, bopvomdsyxc, odm)

Answer (score 7):

Could it be

> the dashboard of a car? The picture was taken through the windscreen which is why there is a reflection of a building.

Comment: Sorry I pipped you to the post by less than a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like it's a

> **drain** of some sort, with the background reflected in it

Comment: One of the words in your first answer is right on target. Hint, not: "of" "with" "the" "in" "it" (Whew, knowing what it is i can't help but think it's too obvious, but maybe not after all)

Comment: the hint just makes it harder lol